# MySql - Join tables, count "distict" the id occurences and caluclate average

Tags: mysql

I need some help, please, with joining two queries.

I have two (or more) tables (same structure), as follows:

```
table_a
+-----------------+-------+
| id |     date   | value |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | 01-05-2018 |    8  |
|  1 | 03-05-2018 |    1  |
|  1 | 04-05-2018 |    1  |
|  1 | 05-05-2018 |    2  |
+----+------------+-------+

table_b
+-----------------+-------+
| id |     date   | value |
+----+------------+-------+
|  2 | 01-05-2018 |   10  |
|  2 | 03-05-2018 |    5  |
|  2 | 04-05-2018 |   10  |
|  2 | 05-05-2018 |    6  |
+----+------------+-------+
```

I'm "joining" them and calculating the AVG value row by row, date by date. This is how I DON'T WANT my results:

```
Result
+-----------------+--------+--------+
| cnt | id |   date        | average|
+----+------------+--------+--------+
|  1   | 1  | 01-05-2018   |   8    | <-- (8)
|  2   | 1  | 03-05-2018   |  4.5   | <-- (8+1=9/2)
|  3   | 1  | 04-05-2018   |  3.3   | <-- (8+1+1=10/3)
|  4   | 1  | 05-05-2018   |    3   | <-- (8+1+1+2=12/4)
|  5   | 2  | 01-05-2018   |  4.4   | <-- (8+1+1+2+10=22/5)
|  6   | 2  | 03-05-2018   |  4.5   | <-- (8+1+1+2+10+5=27/6)
|  7   | 2  | 04-05-2018   |  5.2   | <-- (8+1+1+2+10+5+10=37/7)
|  8   | 2  | 05-05-2018   |  5.3   | <-- (8+1+1+2+10+5+10+6=37/8)
+------+----+--------------+--------+
```

This is how it should be:

```
Result
+-----------------+-------+---------+
| cnt | id |   date       | average |
+----+------------+-------+---------+
|  1   | 1  | 01-05-2018   |   8    | <-- (8)
|  2   | 1  | 03-05-2018   |  4.5   | <-- (8+1=9/2)
|  3   | 1  | 04-05-2018   |  3.3   | <-- (8+1+1=10/3)
|  4   | 1  | 05-05-2018   |    3   | <-- (8+1+1+2=12/4)
|  1   | 2  | 01-05-2018   |   10   | <-- (10)
|  2   | 2  | 03-05-2018   |  7.5   | <-- (10+5=15/2)
|  3   | 2  | 04-05-2018   |  8.3   | <-- (10+5+10=25/3)
|  4   | 2  | 05-05-2018   |  7.7   | <-- (10+5+10+6=25/4)
+------+----+--------------+--------+
```

I'm playing around with this query:

```
select t.cnt,t.id,t.date, (average / cnt) as average 
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as cnt, (@s := @s + value) as average 
      from table_a t 
      cross join (select @rn := 0, @s := 0) params) t 
 UNION ALL 
 select t.cnt,t.id,t.date, (average / cnt) as average 
 from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as cnt, (@s := @s + value) as average
       from table_b t 
       cross join (select @rn := 0, @s := 0) params) t
```

Basically, I need to join the tables, count distinct id occurences and calculate the average of the value, row by row (date) for each id. How can I adjust my query, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have two (or more) tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems to do the job you want. Just use different variable names for the two subqueries:

```
select t.cnt,t.id,t.date, (average / cnt) as average 
from (select t.*, (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as cnt, (@s1 := @s1 + value) as average 
      from table_a t 
      cross join (select @rn1 := 0, @s1 := 0) params) t 
 UNION ALL 
 select t.cnt,t.id,t.date, (average / cnt) as average 
 from (select t.*, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as cnt, (@s2 := @s2 + value) as average
       from table_b t 
       cross join (select @rn2 := 0, @s2 := 0) params) t
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7190b8/2)

Comment: or ( and I would argue, simpler) do the unions first

Comment: @Strawberry You need one additional variable in that case, in order to detect changes in `id` value.

Comment: @Yep, but that's 3 instead of n.